# Java byte array to JTable

Tags: java, arrays, string, swing, jtable

I'm trying to load some hex values into a `JTable`, and I'm trying to get these values from an already populated `byte array`

I've got the table set up with the columns I want, the problem I have now is the best way of getting the hex values into the cells.  In the past I've used `Strings`, which were split, and then loaded into an `Object array` which the `JTable` can use.

However, I can't see an easy way of loading the byte array into the JTable, here's some code I've knocked up.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("c:\\file"));
byte[] buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
fis.read(buffer);

Object[] hexColumns = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(hexColumns, 10);
tesTable.setModel(model); //Assign the model to my JTable (testTable)
```

The question now is the best way of loading the hex values into the table itself.  Here is some code I've used before when using Strings, but I don't really want to convert all the bytes into a String before hand.  Or do I need to?

```
String[] stringSplitArray = inputString.split("!\\*split");
Object[] cellData;

for (int i = 0; i < stringSplitArray.length; i++) {
                cellData = stringSplitArray[i].split("!\\*");
                model.addRow(cellData);
            }
```

This isn't all of the code, but it essentially splits up an initial string, and then splits it again into the individual cells within the table.  However, with the byte values, I'm not sure of the best way of handling this.

Here is the table:

[image]

I'm guessing that it might be possible to cast/convert the byte array to an object array, but I can't see a straight forward way of doing that.

Any information or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could use the byte array as is, and create a custom TableModel that extends from AbstractTableModel. Key would be overriding `getValueAt(...)` to return a String representation of that portion of the byte. A DefaultTableModel could also work, but then you'd have to iterate throw the byte array creating rows of data, and calling `addRow(...)` with the massaged data.

Comment: I find it really odd that there isn't a straight forward way of populating a JTable using existing primitive data sources.  Maybe I'm better off finding a better way of reading and storing the data in the first place.  Thanks.

Comment: Tony: I find that assumption odd. How many different ways are there to hold and display primitive data? To my mind, the number possible ways is truly astounding, and so I wonder of those many many ways, which ones should be pre-made in the Swing library? Rather the library has given you the tools to do this yourself so as to create a model that matches whatever need you have. I'll take its power and flexibility any day.

Comment: could be a nice question with an SSCCE/MCVE

Comment: Ah, Mr. JTable himself, @mKorbel, is in the house. Welcome!

Comment: question is answered in another OPs question

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels thank you, Pete